# Silverlight Transforms Images C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, image

I have an image on which I may use a ScaleTransform to increase the image size by 25%.  I also have a rectangle which sits on top of the image highlighting a particular area.  When I scale the image I want the rectangle to scale as well and highlight the same area as before.  Scaling the rectangle itself isn't the issue, it's getting the rectangle into the correct position so that it highlights the same area.  How do I do this?  Is there a mathematical formula of some description that can be used to calculate its correct position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the same scaling factor to the X and Y offsets of the rectangle.

Comment: It's probably simple but I'm struggling to get my head round what you mean?

Comment: You have the corner of the image itself.  Treat that as coordinate (0,0).  Then you have the same corner of the rectangle.  It is offset from the image by some values, and is therefore at coordinate (x,y).  Whatever scaling factor you apply to the ScaleTransform (in this case, increasing image size by 25%) you can apply to the distance involved (so move the rectangle to (1.25x,1.x25y)).

Comment: I think my difficulty is that I'm looking at it in XAML and I'm going to have to do this in code.  I should have put XAML in the title.

Comment: As in you need to move the rectangle in XAML?

Comment: I've got it working properly in code now, so thanks for the help